# How do I perform a custom login/authentication - Blazor Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor-server-side

I have a Users table in a SQL Server database with ID, Username, Password, Role etc. columns. I want to use that database for logging in / registering a new user.
The end user will use an `Add users` page to add new users and choose their "Role" (I will have a default user in the database).
How do I get the Blazor Server app to do a basic login and authorization check using my custom database and tables?
Here's my User class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; } // Will be used like user role...
}
```

I'm new to Blazor. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure when you created the Blazor app you chose `Individial User Accounts` and the `store user accounts in-app` option as shown below:

[image]

Next in the appsettings.json file, change the DefaultConnection connection string with your SQL Server where you have the database with the `Users` and `Roles` tables to store all the .NET identity information.

Check out this detailed guide for more information on how to implement authentication in a Blazor app using SQL Server:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-authentication-and-authorization-using-blazor-server-side/

Comment: Thanks. How do I add users and roles using a Blazor page?

Comment: Click the register link

Comment: The register link will allow anyone to create an account. I want an admin to create users and assign roles to them. This needs to be done on a 'Add users' page.

Comment: @AndrewChang check out https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/role-based-security-with-blazor-and-identity-server-4-aba12da70049